# How to send Gmail email with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I would like to send email via my gmail address using CodeIgniter. 
I tried many solutions, but none of them work.

My code :

```
  $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'yyyyy',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );


    $this->load->library('email', $config);

    $this->email->from('xxxxx@gmail.com', 'admin');
    $this->email->to('zzzzz@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Email test');
    $msg = "Testing email.";

    $this->email->message($msg);

    $this->email->send();

    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

I have the following error :

```
Message: fwrite(): send of 5 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe
Filename: libraries/Email.php
```

and

```
 Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

For the moment, I'am working in localhost.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I think you didn't allow use of SMTP in your gmail account. You need to check in your google SMTP settings.

Answer (score 1):

In CodeIgniter, you can configure the email data by creating a **email.php** file.
I am using this for a long time. so it could work for you as well.

Inside the file:

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'yourGmailId@gmail.com', // change it to yours
    'smtp_pass' => 'your password', // change it to yours
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE,
    'from' => 'your_from_email@bla.com',
    'subject' => 'test email'
);
```

Now in the controller, you can do this:

```
$this->config->load('email');

    $subject = $this->config->item('subject');
    $from = $this->config->item('from');

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from($from, 'Yards & Acares');
    $data = array(
        'some_data' => $email            
    );

    $this->email->to($email);  // replace it with receiver mail id
    $this->email->subject($subject); // replace it with relevant subject 

    // Here is I have added an email template.
    $body = $this->load->view('admin/propMailer.php', $data, TRUE);

    $this->email->message($body);

    if ($this->email->send()) {
       //Do whatever you want if success
    } else {
       //Do whatever you want if failed 
        log_message('error', 'Unable to Send Email to Customer.' . print_r($this->email->print_debugger(array('headers', 'subject')), TRUE));

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below mentioned solution

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// Set to, from, message, etc.

$result = $this->email->send();
```

Also in php.ini please enable openssl

```
// Find the line.
;extension=php_openssl.dll

// Remove  ";" from this line to enable
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: Should the 'smtp_user' address and the 'from' address should be the same ?

Comment: Somehow yes. Please find this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server

Comment: I can't find the line 'extension=php_openssl.dll' in the php.ini file

Comment: Okay. Then please download openssl extension for php and include this in `ext` directory and add  `extension=php_openssl.dll` at the end if `php.ini` file

Comment: how to download it ?

Comment: You can do googling, but one I found here. http://www.dlldll.com/php_openssl.dll_download.html

Comment: Ok, I have it. Where do I put it ?

Comment: `C:\xampp\php\ext` ->
`use this folder to move your new extension` ->
`add line extension=php_openssl.dll at the end if php.ini`
-> `restart apache/xampp/wamp server and check`

Answer (score 0):

For sending Gmail email on localhost, you can take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44421225/send-email-using-codeigniter-on-localhost/44424745#44424745)

Do this on local development for testing codeigniter email functions.

Comment: what local web server are you using in your linux machine? maybe you should configure SMTP in your linux server